# How to put or create UItabbar above UItoolbar using UINavigation based application in iphone?

Tags: ios4

i want to create tabbar based application..but i want tab bar should be above toolbar....means from below the screen
1. first toolbar with banner add
2.then above toolbar,ther is one tab bar with three tabs
3.now middle of screen there is a view
4. finaly on top of screen there is one navigation bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one toolbar on bottom of screen and then pro-grammatically create Tabbar view with height = self.view.frame.size.height - tool bar height, width = self.view.frame.size.width,  x = 0, y = 0, and finally add as subview on view